# C# Edit line of text file not working

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I'm attempting to use code to edit a line of a text file. I'm using c# on visual studio .Net 4.5 on windows 7.

Here is my code:

```
    public static void Updateconfigfile(bool updateall, int linenotoedit)
    {

        if (updateall == true)
        {
            //update all lines of files
            MessageBox.Show("start  1");
        } else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("start");
            noprojecton = 10;

            //update only a specified line
            //line index for file.readalllines beguins at zero
            string updatestring = Updateconfigfilegetvalue(1);

            string[] textfile = File.ReadAllLines(appdataconfigpath);

            MessageBox.Show(textfile[0]);
            textfile[0] = Updateconfigfilegetvalue(0);
            MessageBox.Show(textfile[0]);


            File.WriteAllLines(appdataconfigpath, textfile);
        }


    }

    public static string Updateconfigfilegetvalue(int lineno)
    {
        //determine which line the user wants to update starts at line 0
        //return the correct line
        string toreturn = "";
        switch(lineno)
        {
            case 0:
                toreturn = ("numberofprojectson: " + noprojecton);
                return toreturn;
            default:
                return "";
        }
    }
```

In the file the current one line of text says 'numberofprojectson: 1'
When i run it, I'm shown the message that says start.

Then a message saying '1' then one saying '10'.

So it is getting the text file in a string array form and changing the 0 index of the array but it isn't writing it to the text file. As the text file still says 'numberofprojectson: 1'.

I have checked the file path and used breakpoints to check all the code is executing and it is executing every line and writing to the correct file.

Any help would be appreciated.

Console Output:

```
'
'Pseudocode Writer.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): Loaded C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\mscorlib\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\mscorlib.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
    'Pseudocode Writer.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'E:\Pseudocode Writer\Pseudocode Writer\bin\Debug\Pseudocode Writer.exe'. Symbols loaded.
    'Pseudocode Writer.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Pseudocode Writer.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Windows.Forms\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Windows.Forms.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
    'Pseudocode Writer.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Pseudocode Writer.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
    'Pseudocode Writer.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Pseudocode Writer.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Drawing\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Drawing.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
    'Pseudocode Writer.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Pseudocode Writer.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Configuration\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Configuration.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
    'Pseudocode Writer.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Pseudocode Writer.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Core\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Core.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
    'Pseudocode Writer.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Pseudocode Writer.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xml\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xml.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
    Exception thrown: 'System.IO.IOException' in mscorlib.dll
    The program '[4276] Pseudocode Writer.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

**App data config path**

```
  public static String appdatapathprovisonal = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData);
 appdatapath = (appdatapathprovisonal + asciicharbackslash + "Pseudocode Writer");
appdataconfigpath = (appdatapath + asciicharbackslash + "config.pwc");
 public static string asciicharbackslash = (Convert.ToChar(92)).ToString();
```

92 ascii code is '\'
.pwc is a text file (.txt)

Exception thrown in console:

```
Exception thrown: 'System.IO.IOException' in mscorlib.dll
```

Comment: After the code to WriteTheFile executes go to the file path and make sure the file update date has changed and open the file in something like notepad and see if the file values has changed.  I am wondering if maybe every time you run the app in visual studio the file is getting overwritten with the original values

Comment: Hi, the appdataconfigpath leads to my programs app data folder and its config.txt file. I check it with notepad after running and it hasn't updated.

Comment: Show us how you're getting `appdataconfigpath` and tell us its value from the debugger. I bet you're looking in the project folder, not the built or deployed file.

Comment: Your code works fine on my machine so it's something specific to your machine. You need to tell us the value of `appdataconfigpath` like I've asked three times now. You should probably use `Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData), "Pseudocode Writer", "config.pwc")` and not try to construct paths with string concatenation. What API are you using? ASP.NET? UWP? You need to run your code [in the debugger](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/), get the exception that's being thrown and add it to your question.

Comment: Exception thrown: 'System.IO.IOException' in mscorlib.dll

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks for all the help. It turns out that this exception occurs when the file is already in use by another process. In my case it was because i had forget to close a stream reader. So, if you ever get this error remember to check that the file isn't being used else way in your program. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

If you're really editing an app.config file (myprogram.exe.config) you have to use the AppSettings to remove/add/modify it.

```
Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
config.AppSettings.Settings.Remove(someKey);
config.AppSettings.Settings.Add(someKey, someText);
config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified);
```

Comment: it is not an app.config file it is just a txt file used to save settings